# something like mouseChildren in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there something in JavaScript similar to `mouseChildren=false` in action-script
to prevent parent's events on children?

Comment: Can you explain further, hopefully with a code sample and the desired behavior?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: you can use event.stopPropagation() https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: @bahmanparsamanesh that would work the other way around though (prevent the event to bubble to the parents)

Comment: Try https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#property_mouseChildren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first register event handler in [capture phase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase) and inside the handler call event's stopPropagation to prevent the event flow down to element's children:

```
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

If you want to completely disable user interaction with some element you can use this css rule:

```
.div1 * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` prevents the event flow to its parent elements, not its child elements. Using that in this situation will give unexpected results.